# PayPal Subscribe button

Tags: wordpress, button, paypal, subscribe

I see that PayPal has removed the recurring donation option that was previously available when people clicked on the donate button on my Wordpress.com website. This is problematic for me so I have tried to embed a Subscribe button, but it is not embedding. The button is not showing. Has anyone had a similar problem and can anyone assist? Many thanks.

Comment: Dear @Annette Gartland StackOverflow is not your senior developer to ask anything whatever in mind. Please describe your code what you tried before facing this kind of problem

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I managed to sort out the problem in the end with the aid of PayPal. Best, Annette

Answer (score 0):

It is better to ask a proper question, but see this. It might help you out.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-email-subscriptions-for-your-wordpress-blog/

Comment: Sorry if that was not a "proper" question! I sorted out my problem in the end. Best, Annette